# InputMismatchException in class

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, methods

I have this class that is supposed to scan a file line by line and parse each line, then print out details of each of the first 10 passengers, which is formatted by a toString method from another class.

```
package experiment9;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.InvalidPathException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class Titanic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Passenger>passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
         try
         {
           Scanner file = new Scanner( new File( "titanic.csv" ) ); 
               while ( file.hasNext( ) ) // test for the end of the file
               {
                   // read a line
                   String line = file.nextLine( );

                   // process the line read
                   Scanner parse = new Scanner( line);
                   parse.useDelimiter( "," );
                   String firstName = parse.next( );
                   String lastName = parse.next( );
                   String gender = parse.next( );
                   String embarked = parse.next( );
                   String survived = parse.next( );
             try
             {
               double age = parse.nextDouble( );
               double fare = parse.nextDouble( );
               int Class = parse.nextInt( );

               Passenger prTemp = new Passenger( firstName, lastName, gender,
                         embarked, survived, age, fare, Class );

               // add Passenger object to passengers array list
               passengers.add( prTemp );  
             }

             catch ( InputMismatchException ime )
             {
                 System.out.println(ime);
                 ime.printStackTrace();
             }
           }

           // release resources associated with titanic.csv
           file.close( );
         }

         catch ( FileNotFoundException fnfe )
         {
           System.out.println( "Unable to find titanic.csv" );
         }

         catch ( Exception e )
         {
           e.printStackTrace( );
         }
                 //supposed to print out details of each 
                 //of the first 10 passengers (still working on this)
         for(int i=0; i<11;i++) {
             System.out.println(passengers.get(i).toString());
         }
        }
```

My main problem is that I get the InputMismatchException as my output, which I am still stuck on fixing. If you need more information, just tell me. Any help is greatly appreciated. As far as the contents of the file being scanned, here is the first 11 or so lines (there is hundreds of lines in the whole file):

```
last,first,gender,age,class,fare,embarked,survived
Braund,Mr. Owen Harris,M,22,3,7.25,Southampton,no
Cumings,Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer),F,38,1,71.2833,Cherbourg,yes
Heikkinen,Miss Laina,F,26,3,7.925,Southampton,yes
Futrelle,Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel),F,35,1,53.1,Southampton,yes
Allen,Mr. William Henry,M,35,3,8.05,Southampton,no
Moran,Mr. James,M,,3,8.4583,Queenstown,no
McCarthy,Mr. Timothy J,M,54,1,51.8625,Southampton,no
Palsson,Master Gosta Leonard,M,2,3,21.075,Southampton,no
Johnson,Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg),F,27,3,11.1333,Southampton,yes
Nasser,Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem),F,14,2,30.0708,Cherbourg,yes
```

Also, here is the class with the toString method I was talking about:

```
package experiment9;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
//Class Name
public class Passenger {

    //Instance fields
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String gender;
    String embarked;
    String survived;
    double age;
    double fare;
    int Class;

    //Constructor
    public Passenger(String firstName, String lastName, String gender,
                        String embarked,String survived, double age, double fare, int Class) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.embarked = embarked;
        this.survived = survived;
        this.age = age;
        this.fare = fare;
        this.Class = Class;
    }

    //toString Method
    public String toString() {

        DecimalFormat MONEY = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

            if(age == -1) {
                return firstName + " " + lastName + "(" + gender + ")" + " from " + 
                        embarked + " paid " + MONEY.format(fare) + " pound for this trip at unknown age";
            }
                else    
            return firstName + " " + lastName + "(" + gender + ")" + " from " + 
                    embarked + " paid " + MONEY.format(fare) + " pound for this trip at the age of " + age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your  [MCVE]

Comment: Your handling of `InputMismatchException` says "file ignored" but you don't break out of the while loop and stop reading the file when that happens, so the file isn't actually ignored. Since you _are_ getting an `InputMismatchException` figure out _that_ error first. That's going to throw other things off. Maybe `System.out.println(ime)` and  `ime.printStackTrace()` when you get it to help you figure it out.

Comment: As a side note, constructing the `MONEY` format is a bit expensive. You can make that a `private static final` variable on the class and reuse it.